# syntax to add setTimeout to function with callback

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, asynchronous, syntax, settimeout

I am trying to make the following 'where will I get in x miles driving towards these target places' asynchronous function (which works well) also wait between executions.  The google maps process has a limit on speed, and I have a few more than the 10 routes that can be plotted before 'Over_Query_limit' kicks in to plot on a map.

I know the terms of service (2500/day), I'm not breaking them.

It sits in a loop with the array of desired destinations(endPoints) from a central point(pt)
What is the syntax to make this happen please?
I have read a lot on this and other sites and can see that the function should be put in quotes but with an asynchronous call I cant see how.

you can see my poor attempt (commented out)

```
var delay=100;
for (var i = 0; i < endPoints.length; i++) {
    //setTimeout(function() {
        howfar(pt,endPoints[i],i,function(i,status,endPoint) {
            //process results
        });
    //},delay;
}

function howfar(from,to,i,callback) {
    //get the endpoint from the directions service
    callback.call({},i,status,endPoint);
}
```

as Always thank you for looking and helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to wait until the `howfar` function returns plus a fixed delay, and only then process the next `endPoint` in the array?

I typically setup an iterator function which schedules itself until there are no more items to be processed. Something like:

```
var delay = 100;
var i = 0;
//define a helper function
var measureNext = function() {

   howfar(pt, endPoints[i], i, function(i,status,endPoint) {
     //process results

     //if there are still unprocessed items in the array, schedule
     //the next after {delay} milliseconds
     if(i++ < endPoints.length) {
       setTimeout(measureNext, delay);
     }
   });

};

//start with the first argument
measureNext();
```

Comment: Well thank you very much!.  You understood precisely, and that works a dream.  I would vote up but I'm a newbie.

Comment: @tonygoodwin you're very welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, too, so it doesn't hang around on the unanswered list forever.

Answer (score 1):

The exact syntax looks like this:

```
var delay = 100; // in milliseconds, 100 is a tenth of a second
setTimeout(function() {
    howfar(pt,endPoints[i],i, function(i,status,endPoint) {
        //process results
    });
}, delay);
```

A quick Google would have turned this up, though.

Comment: Thank you - that confirms what I had in the quote (commented out!)  I guess the problem is that when doing it that way I didnt experience any reduction in the over_query_limit responses, but I appreciate your answer.